# Транслит в MySQL

Tags: mysql

При переносе сайта с одного хостинга на другой перестала работать функция транслита, на старом работает, на новом нет. Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем проблема.
Запрос в phpmyadmin: SELECT translit_func('русский в траслит') Результат:aaaaaaa-a-aaaaaaa

```
    DELIMITER $$
   CREATE FUNCTION `translit_func`(`_txt` VARCHAR(250)) RETURNS text CHARSET     utf8
BEGIN
   DECLARE _f varchar(5);
   DECLARE _t varchar(15);
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT f,t from translit;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
open cur;
the_loop: LOOP

#get the values of each column into our variables
FETCH cur INTO _f,_t;
IF done THEN
  LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;
set _txt=replace(_txt,_f,_t);   
END LOOP the_loop;

CLOSE cur;
return _txt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Таблица translit

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `translit` (
   `t` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    `f` varchar(15) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   INSERT INTO `translit` (`t`, `f`) VALUES
 ('a', 'а'),
 ('b', 'б'),
 ('v', 'в'),
 ('g', 'г'),
 ('d', 'д'),
 ('e', 'е'),
 ('e', 'ё'),
 ('zh', 'ж'),
 ('z', 'з'),
 ('i', 'и'),
 ('y', 'й'),
 ('k', 'к'),
 ('l', 'л'), ... и т.д.
```

Comment: Какая ошибка,опишите?

Comment: в phpmyadmin: SELECT translit_func('русский в траслит') Результат:aaaaaaa-a-aaaaaaa

Comment: надо смотреть настройки базы на старом хостинге и на новом, на версии и т.д. попробуйте заюзать внешнюю программу а не phpmyadmin для выполнения процедуры.

Comment: Тех поддержка хостинга говорит, что у них установлена совершенно стандартная версия MySQL

Comment: Зачем использовать транслит при наличии utf-8, да ещё и в базе? о_О

Comment: Значения фильтров в урле, например site.ru/kvartira/2-komnatnaya/rajon-leninskij/ulica-lenina/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо было поменять настройки базы, которые по умолчанию были не те что надо

```
character_set_database  latin1 --> utf8
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci --> utf8_general_ci
```